# Scripts in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Another question I have is this; I want to execute a script (docs()) when you click text, I've tried using this code:

```
<p><span class="skill">Documentation can be found here.<script>docs()</script></span></p>
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript.  Executing code in response to a click event will be covered by just about any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

```
<p><span class="skill" onclick="docs()">Documentation can be found here.</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClass('skill')[0].onclick = docs;
```